# Swift #available keyword vs respondsToSelector

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2

According to the [pre-release Swift 2 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8) there is now an `#available` keyword that can be used with an `if let` or `guard` statement for checking API availability. It gives the following example:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
if #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.10, *) {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

Or

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
guard #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.10, *) else { return }
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Which it (the doc) states is the equivalent of the following Objective-C code:

```
if ([CLLocationManager instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
  // Method is available for use.
} else {
  // Method is not available.
}
```

Obviously `respondsToSelector:` only works on subclasses of `NSObject` whereas the `#available` keyword will work even for "pure" Swift code, so I appreciate that advantage.

However since starting iOS development I've always been led to believe that the best practice for this situation is to detect the presence of an API rather than rely on the version it was introduced.

As a more concrete example I'm thinking of when Apple introduced `firstObject` on `NSArray` in iOS 7 but retroactively made it available back to iOS 4 (where it was available, but private). Any code using `respondsToSelector:` would have worked on iOS < 7 but obviously a version check would fail.

Are there any benefits to shifting to the `#available` keyword that I've missed?

Comment: @holex They are both runtime solutions.

Comment: I think the reason is that Swift doesn't allow us to create references to functions or methods (other than textual) and that's dangerous, too. Using any kind of `respondsToSelector` in Swift looks ugly because you have to specify the name of the method as a string (also in Obj-C method name convention) :) I am not sure `#available` is an improvement but it it will help code consistency because there will be Swift only frameworks sooner or later. On the other hand, the version check is available for system version only so for external libraries you will still have to use selector checking.

Comment: @Sulthan External (Swift 2) libraries can annotate their own API with the `@availability` keyword. As a side note I'm not sure on the compatibility between using `if #available...` with Objective-C methods annotated with `NS_AVAILABLE`. I completely agree that `respondsToSelector:` has it's issues even in Objective-C, and having to specify the selector as a string in Swift is just terrible. I'm all for a nicer way, but #available seems (to me) like a side-step rather than a step forward.

Comment: I have the same feeling about it.

Comment: AFAIK The situation with `firstObject` method wouldn't be possible with Swift. And because it is not possible, I would assume that `if #available` method is good for all cases in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

A big advantage is that the Swift 2 compiler in Xcode 7 compares the
availability of classes, methods, properties, ... against the deployment
target of your project.

Using `respondsToSelector` was always error-prone. For Objective-C,

```
if ([CLLocationManager instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
```

the compiler only verifies if `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is some
known method, but it cannot verify if that check is logically correct.

In Swift it is even worse because selectors can only be specified as
strings and the compiler does not verify anything.

With Swift 2/Xcode 7, the corresponding code

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
if locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization") {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

does not compile anymore if the deployment target is less than iOS 8,
the error message is

```
error: 'requestWhenInUseAuthorization()' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                            ^
note: add 'if #available' version check
```

With

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
if #available(iOS 8.0, OSX 10.10, *) {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

the compiler knows that the method will only be called on iOS 8 and later
and does not complain.

Comment: Yeh I saw that in the docs, I guess my question doesn't really have an answer. It just seems strange to me that they didn't provide something like the optional protocol method syntax for checking API: `if locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization? { locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() } else { // method is not available }`

Comment: @SteveWilford: `if #available` works not only with classes and methods but also with properties. If I remember correctly, something like `if someInstance.someOptionalProperty? { ... }` is not possible in Swift. There was a discussion on SO or in the Apple Developer Forum, but I haven't found it again.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered optional properties. `if #someInstance.someOptionalProperty { ... }` starts getting silly, I guess this is why I'm not a compiler engineer. Maybe after a few encounters with `#available` I'll get used to it...

Answer (score 1):

`respondsToSelector` checks the the runtime to see if the selector is present. `#available` checks the published SDK to see if it's included. In the WWDC video, they explicitly said that many public APIs start as private APIs in earlier OS versions. Which means in some cases it won't be `#available` even though it `respondsToSelector`