# Check function availability watchOS 3 Xcode 8 vs watchOS 2 in objective c

Tags: objective-c, version-control, watchos-2, ios10, watchos-3

I have added some watchOS 3 features to an existing watchOS 2 as I have to support both WatchOS 2 and WatchOS 3 devices so I need to check the function availability before it gets called. for example in ExtensionDelegate I have this function which only WatchOS 3 devices should call it, how can I check the WatchOS version in objective c.

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground {

    [self scheduleRefreshBackgroundTask];

}
```

I have read [How to check iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version) but I'm still confused how to check it in objective c.

Comment: that link has objective version too. What else do you need ?

Comment: I need to know the equivalent of this for WatchOS 3 and in objective c --> if #available(iOS 10, *) {}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518548/swift-available-keyword-vs-respondstoselector

Comment: Thanks Teja, this one is in Swift too but I need it in Objectve c. It seems with Swift its so easy to check the API availability

Comment: There is no direct replacement of #Available in obj-c. The equivalent of #available in swift is to use instancesRespondToSelector in obj-c

Comment: based on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/how-to-check-ios-version I don't know how to use [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion] to compare the os version

Comment: Use [[NSProcessInfo processInfo]operatingSystemVersion] to get the string value of the OS version

Comment: but operatingSystemVersion doesn't return a string value.

Comment: Did you try it ? What does NSLog(@"%@",[[NSProcessInfo processInfo]operatingSystemVersion] ) gives you ?

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and it's not compiled.

Comment: I'm sure that line will not cause a crash.Please post the crash stack trace, and also add some relevant code of what caused the crash.

Comment: the error message is: "Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'NSOperatingSystemVersion' . I put the line of the code in ExtensionDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that by adding `WK_AVAILABLE_WATCHOS_ONLY(3.0)` I can control the watchOS versions when I need to add the watchOS 3 features to an existing watchOS 2 project and make them compatible:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground
{
   [self scheduleRefreshBackgroundTask];
} 

- (void)scheduleRefreshBackgroundTask WK_AVAILABLE_WATCHOS_ONLY(3.0)
{
    // do something
}
```